# Why is there a space after lines even after I set to "zero" spacing and indentations in all boxes?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Why is there a space after lines even after I set to "zero" spacing and indentations in all boxes?

> [image]

And this is what I see after turning on display of hidden characters:

> [image]

Comment: Turn on display of hidden characters to get a better idea of what is going on.
See [Nonprinting Formatting Marks](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NonprintChars.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill. The shortcut for this is **Ctrl+Shift+8** (**Ctrl+***).

Comment: Looks like you have blank lines between the text lines.

Comment: You’ve probably got double CR/LFs or some other hidden code. Enable Show Codes by clicking the button with the paragraph mark icon, next to the Sort button, and delete the offending characters/codes.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I posted "hidden characters " picture also.

Comment: This was cross-posted and answered in the Microsoft Word Forum. https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/47033-how-use-remove-these-spaces-automatically.html  Please read and follow the guidance in this Message to Cross-Posters: https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can use Replace in Word

I count 42 tab characters (the little arrow).
The shortcut for Replace is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in the Windows version.

In that dialog:

- Find: `^t`
- Replace with: (nothing)

Replace all.
Hit the Replace All button.

See also [Cleaning Up Pasted Text](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CleanWebText.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill and [Cleaning Up Pasted Text](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/29880-cleaning-up-text-pasted-websites-e-mails.html) by Word MVP Paul Edstein

Comment: how did you find correct formulae: `^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t^t` for 42 tab characters?

Comment: Surely, entering simply ^t (1 time instead of 21 or whatever) as the search text would accomplish exactly the same thing here.

Comment: You are correct. A single ^t and Replace All will do the same thing. I am amending by answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on that image that shows hidden characters, it seems like each of those lines is filled to the brim with tab and spaces characters.

So while your 0cm adjustments are valid, if each line just has a pile of extraneous tab and space characters in place, that would naturally push the lines down. You need to trim each line to something where it is just the text; not that extra stuff.

I honestly don’t use Microsoft Word anymore, but based on the advice from [this website](https://us4b.co.uk/removing-leading-trailing-spaces-in-word/), the solution would be to select all of the text, and then do a little alignment dance of center align the content, right align the content and then left align the content like this; paraphrased from that site:

1. Select all of the lines with leading and/or trailing spaces.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to center align them.
3. Keeping the lines selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to do right align. This will remove trailing spaces.
4. Still keeping the lines selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to do left align. This will remove leading spaces.

When that is done, the text should be all trimmed and cleaned with only the pure text present on each line.